# This is what python returns while I'm trying to tokenize tweets : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, twitter

I'm trying to tokenize all my tweets that I previously saved in json file. I follow this example: https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/09/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-2/

```
import re
import json
 
emoticons_str = r"""
    (?:
        [:=;] # Eyes
        [oO\-]? # Nose (optional)
        [D\)\]\(\]/\\OpP] # Mouth
    )"""
 
regex_str = [
    emoticons_str,
    r'<[^>]+>', # HTML tags
    r'(?:@[\w_]+)', # @-mentions
    r"(?:\#+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)", # hash-tags
    r'http[s]?://(?:[a-z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&amp;+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]))+', # URLs
 
    r'(?:(?:\d+,?)+(?:\.?\d+)?)', # numbers
    r"(?:[a-z][a-z'\-_]+[a-z])", # words with - and '
    r'(?:[\w_]+)', # other words
    r'(?:\S)' # anything else
]
    
tokens_re = re.compile(r'('+'|'.join(regex_str)+')', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
emoticon_re = re.compile(r'^'+emoticons_str+'$', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
 
def tokenize(s):
    return tokens_re.findall(s)
 
def preprocess(s, lowercase=False):
    tokens = tokenize(s)
    if lowercase:
        tokens = [token if emoticon_re.search(token) else token.lower() for token in tokens]
    return tokens
```

When I add this at the end everything is working:

```
tweet = 'RT @marcobonzanini: just an example! :D http://example.com #NLP'
print(preprocess(tweet))
```

I want to tokenize my tweets that I saved in JSON file and the website suggests to do it this way:

```
with open('mytweets.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
        do_something_else(tokens)
```

This is how I'm trying to open my JSON file:

```
with open('data/digitalhealth.json', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         tweet = json.loads(line)
...         tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
...         do_something_else(tokens)
```

And this is what python returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Does anyone know how to sort this out? I'm new to all this and I really don't have any idea what to do.

This is my code for collecting Data from Twitter's API:

```
import tweepy
import json
API_KEY = 'xxx'
API_SECRET = 'xxx'
TOKEN_KEY = 'xxx'
TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxx'


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET)



api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

query = '#digitalhealth'
cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, lang="en")


for page in cursor.pages():
    tweets = []
    for item in page:
        tweets.append(item._json)

with open('Twitter_project/digitalhealth.json', 'wb') as outfile:
    json.dump(tweets, outfile)
```

How do I change it now so I will have only dictionaries?
Thanks all of you for your help! I really appreciate it

Comment: Apparently `tweet` is a list in your case, not a dictionary. We can't tell you why, it's what is returned from parsing one line of your file as JSON.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you for your answer. This is what I store in my file: `[{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "RT @ForesightMC: Google's new research app shows participants how their data is driving health insights\n\nVia @MobiHealthNews\n#DigitalHealth\u2026", "is_quote_status": false, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "id": 1337663189505466369, "favorite_count": 0, "entities": {"symbols": [], "user_mentions": [{"id": 854310750894141440, "indices": [3, 15], "id_str": "854310750894141440", "screen_name": "ForesightMC", "name": "Dr Alix Daniel"}`

Comment: This is only part of it but the structure of tweets look like I have posted above

Comment: So you want to access the dictionary inside the list. Do you know how you can access items from a list?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, but I didn't realise that I was storing my JSON dictionaries in lists... as mentioned by tralph3 I would like to store them as dictionaries.. Could you please help me fix it? I will edit my post and add my code where I collect data from Twitter's REST API

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you're storing your JSON dictionaries in lists... You should try to store them as dictionaries since that'd be much easier for you, but if you want to access them now then simply do: `tweet[0]` to access the dictionary, and from there you can access the dictionary data like so `tweet[0]['text']`. Still, look into reformatting the JSON properly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion @tralph3 . I have just added another code for collecting and storing data from Twitter's API. Could you please tell me how to change it so I will have only dictionaries?

Comment: I don't know what the Twitter API sends as an answer, but somewhere in the process you're getting lists of dictionaries instead of raw dictionaries. First identify where this happens and if possible try to omit it, if not, you can make something like `if type(answer) == list: answer = answer[0]` to retrieve the dictionary. It's not really something I can answer without looking at the code directly but I hope that helps.